# Research around users navigating native app then being redirected to a web page

Tags: user-expectation, android, ios

I'm looking for some research on the following scenario:

- users are navigating within a native app - they want to purchase some addons
- They press on the get addons button and then they are then redirected to the website.

I was wondering if there was any research that currently exists on what users perceptions are to this and what the impact is in terms of trust (they are essentially following a journey to make a payment) and also cash of use.

Is this jarring to a users expectation and what are the emotions that result from this?

I know the best way to get this information is to user test and that is something we intend on doing, but for now I'm looking for some existing research or experience on this.

Comment: I don't have any research, and I'd scrutinize any that you find very closely. The results would depend a lot on what the web experience is like. If it's a non-responsive unreadable site, then yes, that will be jarring. If it's a site that matches the app in look and feel, then probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Any research you could find would be almost entirely specific to their specific use case. There are a lot of factors that could potentially affect how fitting this kind of workflow is, including but definitely not limited to:

- the layout of the mobile site (as [@KenMohnkern mentions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/119295/research-around-users-navigating-native-app-then-being-redirected-to-a-web-page#comment191409_119295))
- who your target users are
- your application's domain
- the manner in which you present this to the user

I cannot speak to the first three factors, as I have no information on those. The last point can be addressed by preparing the user that the application is about to open a web page. Something like <kbd>Open Web Store</kbd> or <kbd>Shop Online</kbd><sup>1</sup> or similar could be sufficient to inform your users of this workflow.

---

<sup>1: Yes, I know that applications can be "online" as well, but a lot of users think of their browser as "The Internet". This was why it was so important for Microsoft to [keep the blue 'e' icon](http://money.cnn.com/2015/04/29/technology/microsoft-edge-windows-build/?iid=EL) when they replaced Internet Explorer with Edge. In any case, testing with various wording would be easy and wise.</sup>

Comment: It is quite a good responsive website. I'm attempting to look at ways of providing what might be the benefits of doing this in app rather than breaking to web.  I am maybe a little bit biased in the fact that I would like this to be a complete app experience just purely because this is what I have been tasked to do.

But also, if the users prefer the break to web method and don't have any issues with it I have to try to remain unbiased. Unfortunately we don't have the drop-off rates yet when navigating out to web, so I have nothing to base my proposal for developing the feature to be in app.